# android studio logcat spamed with "android system / linux errors"

Tags: android, error-handling, logcat

My logcat get spamed by the same error block again and again. (every second)

I know how to use filters and how to get myapp logs, but i want to know what this errors mean. I tried to google them, but get no good idea about them. It seems, that they are coming from the android system and i think they have an effect on my android performance.

So if someone can give me a hint, what they mean, i would be very glad.

Logcat

```
12-23 00:14:34.420 5116-5122/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: poll() has timed out for /sys/module/msm_performance/events/cpu_hotplug
12-23 00:14:34.422 5116-5122/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL:  before pthread_cond_wait 1762, chk_core_online_poll
12-23 00:14:34.422 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Calling Generic reset function - reset_to_default_values
12-23 00:14:34.423 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESETHANDLER: Warning: core_ctl_max_cpu property not defined, can not reset
12-23 00:14:34.423 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESETHANDLER: Warning: core_ctl_min_cpu property not defined, can not reset
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/interactive/ignore_hispeed_on_notif, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5122/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL:  after pthread_cond_wait 1764, chk_core_online_poll
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5122/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL:  after pthread_mutex_unlock 1767, chk_core_online_poll
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5122/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Block on poll()
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/hispeed_freq, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/above_hispeed_delay, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/target_loads, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/min_sample_time, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/go_hispeed_load, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.434 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/max_freq_hysteresis, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.435 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/timer_rate, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.435 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/timer_slack, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.435 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/io_is_busy, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.435 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/boost, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.435 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/boostpulse_duration, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.435 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/use_sched_load, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.435 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/use_migration_notif, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.435 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: read/write failed for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/interactive/ignore_hispeed_on_notif, rc=0
12-23 00:14:34.441 5116-5120/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Applying the Current Profile -1 again since cores are online..
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just ignore such errors. As long your smartphone works good, thy don't have an effect on it.